# Click on a link in Selenium: find_element_by_link_text doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am going to click on a link via selenium but it doesn't work when I applied  find_element_by_link_text
as a following : (URL: https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing )

HTML Code

```
<a class href="/positivewellbeing/posts">Posts</a>
```

Selenium Code :

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Posts').click()
```

I don't have any error, but this code line didn't run or work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `.element_to_be_clickable` before clicking:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Posts'))).click()

#update here
wait.until(EC.url_to_be('https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts'))
print(driver.current_url)
```

The following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Based on your comments, if you want to wait for the url to change to the way you want, please use `EC.url_to_be`. Because `time.sleep (...)` is a bad way, please see the above updated code.

See more about **`expected_conditions`** here :

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#expected-conditions-support

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I did what you said, but it doesn't work still. To check whether it worked, I put " print(driver.current_url). it should return "https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing/posts" but it returns "https://healthunlocked.com/positivewellbeing"

Comment: @TaherehMaghsoudi make sure you closed "Our use of cookies" notification before clicking Posts link

Comment: Yeah, at the beginning I did it by this code line : # closing cookies thing 
driver.find_element_by_id('ccc-notify-accept').click()

Comment: I can solve it by putting a time.sleep. "driver.find_element_by_link_text('Posts').click()
time.sleep(3)
print (driver.current_url)" Now it works . Thanks guys

Comment: @TaherehMaghsoudi glad it worked, but if you want wait until the url changes please see the above updated code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net you can try to use Coypu library in your project:

https://github.com/featurist/coypu
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Coypu/

Coypu it's a wrapper that will save you from retries, sleeps (waits).

It supports browser automation in .Net to help make tests readable, robust, fast to write and less tied to a UI. If your tests are littered with sleeps, retries, complex XPath expressions and IDs then Coypu might help.

Coypu is on Nuget:

```
PM> Install-Package Coypu
```

I work in a project where we have around 3k automated tests developed with C# and Selenium and my life would be kind of miserable without Coypu.

Your code will look the same when using Coypu but the sleep will be automatically handled by the library, it's transparent to the user:

```
Browser.FindXPath("//*[contains(text(), 'Posts')]").Click();

Browser.FindIdEndingWith("Posts").Click();
```